# Calculating age from social security number - how?

Tags: c#, date, int

I'm pretty new to C# and got this assignment. I have a class called person with some details, of which one is the social security number (CPR number). From this number I need to calculate the age of this person. It needs to fit in this, according to assignment, if i understand it right:

```
public class Person
{
    int _Cpr;

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return (age calculation from cpr number somehow)
        }
    }
}
```

I however have no idea how to do so - I'm guessing I need to compare the social security number integer having this form: DDMMYYXXXX to the current date, and return the difference in rounded down years - but I have no idea how to do so.

---

I'm starting to get the picture as how to calculate the age - What I'm still lost on, is how to fit this into the code i have. The description I have says that the Age should be a "calculated property" - But I can't create variables to use inside a class definition as far as i know, so i can't really do all the steps required to make Cpr into Age - Can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is homework so let me try to push you in the right direction instead of simply providing the answer.

You have to extract the birth date from the social security number. By doing integer divisions by powers of 10 you can "chop" of digits from the right. By doing modulo operations by powers of 10 you can keep the number of digits you need:

```
123456/100 = 1234
1234%100 = 34
```

In C# you can use the `DateTime` class to represent a point in time (e.g. the birth date). The field `DateTime.Now` contains the current time.

You want to get the age in years (rounded down) so you will have substract the `Year` property of the two `DateTime` values. You also have to take into account if the person already had his birthday this year.

---

**Spoiler ahead**

The largest CPR is 3112999999 and that number is actually larger than `Int32.MaxValue`. This means that you have to change the type of `_Cpr` to `uint` (or `long`). The code below also takes into account the rule described by TheKaneda to get the four digit year from the two digit year.

```
public class Person       
{       
  uint _Cpr;       

  public int Age       
  {       
    get       
    {       
      int century = (int) ((cpr/1000)%10);

      int shortBirthYear = (int) ((cpr/10000)%100);
      int birthYear = 1900 + shortBirthYear;
      if ((century == 4 || century == 9) && shortBirthYear <= 36)
        birthYear += 100;
      else if (5 <= century && century <= 8 && shortBirthYear <= 57)
        birthYear += 100;

      int birthMonth = (int) ((cpr/1000000)%100);

      int birthDayOfMonth = (int) ((cpr/100000000));

      DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDayOfMonth);
      DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
      DateTime birthDay = new DateTime(today.Year, birthMonth, birthDayOfMonth);

      int birthdayAdjustment = today < birthDay ? -1 : 0;
      int age = today.Year - birthDate.Year + birthdayAdjustment;
    }
  }
}
```

Even though the code is surprisingly complex it doesn't handle the situation when a person is born on February 29. To improve the code it should be refactored into separate parts that deals with extracting the birth date and calculating the age. The last part should deal with the Feburary 29 issue and depending on culture you may discover that in non-leap year people born on February 29 celebrate their birthday February 28.

Comment: I was following you until this: "birthDay ? -1 : 0;" - I haven't used that operator yet - I got somehing wrong though, i thought it was inpossible to declare variables to use inside a class

Comment: @Treelink: I have removed the conditional operator. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I actually think i understand this code - My head is full of i-don't-know-what, but i get it and i think i can reproduce - Thank you! :) (I really had no idea it could be done like this, and I'd never have worked it out on my own!)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have written, be aware that ideally (for production use, although your assignment may not require it), you need to check the 7th digit to account for the century of birth.

```
ddmmyy-Cxxx
C = 0-3 => person was born in the 1900's
C = 4 or 9 => person was born either 2000-2036 or 1937-1999
C = 5-8 => person was born either 2000-2057 or 1858-1899
```

Comment: It is true that for a real Danish social security number you have to this but apparently for this assignment it has been redefined as DDMMYYYYXXXX with a four digit year probably to avoid this added complexity.

Comment: Ah, right - that's likely it - removed my comment on your answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just updated, the CPR-number indeed only has a total of 10 digits in Denmark. My mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [Convert.ToDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx)

I'm sure you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you the exact code you need, as this looks like homework, but I will give you a few clues.

First, a CPR number in the format DDMMYYYYXXXX looks like an int, but in fact it is not one. You may look at it as either a struct with 4 different fields (D, M, Y, X) or as a string. Maybe the most convenient can be infered from the subsequent hints, though.

You can convert a date in .Net, represented by the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) struct to a string with the [ToString( string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method in wich you can specify a custom format. You can do the reverse with the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

Now if you have a birthday, calculating the age should be pretty easy. It is equal to the difference between the current year and the birth year if we are after the birthday in this year, and one less otherwise. Implementing it should not be too difficult.